# Google maps api request using components issues with postal code

Tags: google-maps

I am having an issue with finding an address when all I have is the street number + street name and a postal code (assuming in US).

Using url parameters like:

```
address=1234+street+rd%2C12345%2Cunited+states
```

seems to always interpret <12345> as part of the street, like a sub unit or something. Using components parameters like:

```
address=1234+street+rd%2Cunited+states&components=postal_code:12345
```

will find the correct postal code but does not return the address information for the specific location like street number and name.

If I also add the route component and specify the street name then the full address information will be returned. Likewise if I use the locality component, then the full information will be returned:

```
address=1234+street+rd&components=locality:city+land|postal_code:12345
address=1234+street+rd&components=route:street+rd|postal_code:12345
```

The issue is I am using the geocoder to parse the addresses so I am relying on a full address response to get the components. In this specific case Im assuming the user only entered a postal code and street info so I dont have the option to include locality (without using a second maps calls) nor do I want to assume Ive broken down the street info correctly.

Can anybody shed some light on possible issues Im running into or possibly how to make a maps api call with only street number, street name, postal code, and country being known?

Answer (score 1):

The Geocoding API documentation says the following:

> A query containing a component filter only returns the geocoding results that match the filter. If no matches are found, the geocoder returns a result that matches the filter itself.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering

So, if `address=1234+street+rd%2Cunited+states&components=postal_code:12345` founds a postal code it is likely because the address is missing from Google database.

You have an option to report missing addresses as described here:

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094045?hl=en&ref_topic=3093612

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is just a bug with the api. The address I am testing with also does not appear in a broad search either when I only input street info. It returns 3 other results with the same street info but not my specific address.